Unexpected order of evaluation when using short circuit operators
Running the code below
print(print('1') or print('2') and print('3') or print('4'))

will result in:
1
2
4
None

I know that the priority is not > and > or, so I expected
2
1
4
None

I don't understand that result. Please explain it.

or is short circuiting and won’t evaluate its right hand operand if the left hand operand is true. There’s no way this would result in the 2 1 evaluation order.

Re-open vote reason: No duplicate has been submitted (yet) and this question highlights the importance of distinguishing priority/precedence and order of evaluation, and also return values vs. side effects. I use short-circuit operators a lot, but this question made me realize that most of the logic I use employing them is implicit, based on experience, but never wrote down the rules explicitly. Anyway, I think this is a good question about a topic that seems deceptively straightforward.

The short answer is the excellent summary by user interjay from the comments:

Precedence determines where to add parentheses. It doesn't change the order of evaluation of operands of a specific operator.

The long answer:
print() returns None and has "side effects"
print() returns None (see this SO thread), but its side effect is to print on the standard output.
>>> a = print('1')
1

>>> print(a)
None

Dismissing the outer print statement, your code
print('1') or print('2') and print('3') or print('4')

becomes
None or None and None or None

and will return None.
Priority and order of code execution
Operator priority only determines how statements should be "grouped" for evaluation, but the rules of "short circuiting", combined with functions with "side effects", will may seem to break the rules.
To paraphrase the rules linked above:

Rule 0
The first argument of a short-circuiting statement is ALWAYS evaluated.

The evaluation of the second argument depends on the behaviour of the short-circuit operator:

Rule 1
or only evaluates the second argument if the first one is false.
Rule 2
and only evaluates the second argument if the first one is true.

So, given the priority and the rules above and assigning their output to a variable,
print('1') or print('2') and print('3') or print('4')
--- a ----    --- b ----     --- c ----    --- d ----

your code will become
a or (( b and c ) or d)   

The steps of execution according to the rules above:

As per rule 0, print('1') is evaluated.

print('1')'s return value is None, a "false-y" value, so given rule 1, we continue to
( print('2') and print('3') ) or (...)
  --None----     --None----


According to the priority rules, the and statement has to be evaluated first.
print('2') and print('3')

The first argument, print('2') is evaluated. Even though it prints 2, it will return a "false-y" value (None), so according to rule 2, print('3') is skipped.

The or statement will become
( print('2') and print('3') ) or (...)
  --None----     --None----
------------ None -----------

That is:
None or print('4')

so according to rule 1, print('4') is executed.

Stop (there is nothing else to evaluate).



We have broken down the Python code provided step by step, considering the precedence of operators and how the print() function behaves:
print(print('1') or print('2') and print('3') or print('4'))

The result of

print('1')

is None because print() always returns None.
the expression looks like:
None or **print('2')** and **print('3')** or **print('4')**

The expression becomes:
None and print('3')

now we have:
None or None or print('4')

Final operation: print('4')
Final Output:
1
2
4
None

